# When should you use swap or reset

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between using `swap!` and `reset!` in Clojure functions? I have seen from the clojure.core docs that they are used to change the value of an atom but I am not sure when to use `swap!` and when to use `reset!`.

What circumstances would you use `swap!` and which circumstances would you use `reset!`?

```
[:input {:type "text"
         :value @time-color
         :on-change #(reset! time-color (-> % .-target .-value))}]
```

The above code is an example of using `reset!` for a button

```
[:input.form-control
          {:type      :text
           :name      :ric
           :on-change #(swap! fields assoc :ric (-> % .-target .-value))
           :value     (:ric @fields)}]
```

And this button uses `swap!`

Are `swap!` and `reset!` interchangeable?

Thanks

Comment: `swap!` is used for updates based on the current value, `reset!` just sets the new value without any consideration for the current value.

Comment: As minimally as possible

Comment: They are interchangeable. Swap invoke the function at java level while with reset you send a value to java. Swap! is ok i you pass a function where atom is tyhe first arg...which is not always the case so you use (reset! my-atom (f arg0  ...@my-atom ...))

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`swap!` uses a function to modify the value of the atom.  You will usually use `swap!` when the current value of the atom matters.  For example, incrementing a value depends on the current value, so you would use the `inc` function.

`reset!` simply sets the value of the atom to some new value.  You will usually use this when you just want to set the value without caring what the current value is.

```
(def x (atom 0))
(swap! x inc)   ; @x is now 1
(reset! x 100)  ; @x is now 100
(swap! x inc)   ; @x is now 101
```

Comment: May also be worth noting that the *reason* to use swap! when the next val depends on the old is to gain the advantage of atomicity

(reset! x (inc @x)) is not thread-safe, whereas (swap! x inc) is