# Clojure: swap and reset to change identifier value

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure.

I have used to change value of identifier using `swap!` and `reset!`.

**reset!**

`(def item (atom "Apple"))`

`user=> @item`

**Out Put** ;;=> "Apple"

`(reset! item "Grapes")`

`user=> @item`

**Out Put** ;;=> "Grapes"

**swap!**

`(def item (atom "Apple"))`

`user=> @item`

**Out Put** ;;=> "Apple"

`(swap! item (#(str %) "PineApple"))`

**Out Put** ;;=> `ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`

How can I change value of item by using **swap!**?

Comment: Your `(#(str %) "PineApple")` there runs at once and returns `"PineApple"`.  This is why you get the error (`swap!` expects a function there not a string).

Comment: @cfrick Very helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844794/when-should-you-use-swap-or-reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(swap! item (fn [old] "PineApple"))
```

or:

```
(swap! item (fn [_] "PineApple"))
```

But as you are discarding the input, `reset!` is better here:

```
(reset! item "PineApple")
```

Comment: What is "old" here?

Comment: The old value of item, inside the atom, so that would be "Apple".

Comment: Were you wanting to concatenate "Apple" and "Pineapple" together? Trying to think what the intention was with `(str %)`. If so I can give an example of doing that in the answer as well.

Comment: No, I did not want to concatenate? Your answer perfectly useful to me. Thanks @Chris Murphy.

Comment: I tried the same by replacing to "s" `(swap! item (fn[s] "Banana"))`. This also works. Now I understood syntax of `swap!`

Comment: Because you are not using the `s`, you could have `_` instead. The same goes for `old`, it could be `_`. But I'll leave my answer as it is because you ask about `old` in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

As per `swap!` syntax `(swap! atom f)`. swap should require function.

So I just tried to solve the issue in this way.

`(swap! item (fn[s] "Banana"))`

**Output** ;;=> Banana